# Login no funciona, asp core con Vue - Cors o Configuracion

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012, cors

Estoy haciendo una app con asp core 2.1 y Vue. Mi problema es el inicio de sesión en el servidor de producción (Windows Server 2012 R2). Cuando quiero loguerme arroja el siguiente error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://{ip...}/api/account/login' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of
>   undefined
>       at eval (Login.vue?03db:289)

Todas los demás endpoints responden excepto el del login.

Sin embargo, cuando pruebo en el backend de desarrollo apuntando a la BD de producción, loguea sin problemas y todos los endpoints también responden (get, post etc). Por lo que puedo entender que puede ser un tema de configuración, tal vez en el servidor relacionado con IIS. Según entiendo si fuera un asunto de CORS ningún endpoint funcionaría ¿Es así?. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Codigo de startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;

            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => 
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = "yourdomain.com",
                ValidAudience = "yourdomain.com",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Llave_secreta"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            });

        //Servicio de Email
        services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));


        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddCors();
        //Autorizacion a recursos de la aplicación
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(ConfigureJson);

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();


        }); 
    }


    private void ConfigureJson(MvcJsonOptions obj) {
        obj.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    );

        //app.UseSession();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Codido de Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
    }
```

Comment: Si es un servidor de producción porque intenta acceder al localhost? 'http://localhost:8000'

Comment: No intento acceder a 'localhost:8000'. Ese es el origen de las peticiones, es decir, Vue usando localhost:8000 dentro de la configuracion de vue  esta apunta al backend de produccion. Funcionan todos los endpoint menos el del login.

Comment: Podría ser por la ruta, debería ser https?